# For each set of functions, indicate its mathematical expression

Tags: conic-sections

Could you help me please with the following problem.

For each set of functions, indicate its mathematical expression:

**a)** parabolas that pass through the origin and the point $(1,1)$

**b)** circles tangent to the x-axis and whose center is over the line $x = 1$

---

**Edit**

For the parabolas I got $c=0$ and $a+b=1$.

Comment: Show us  your work. What have you tried for this Problem?

Comment: I do not know what to do

Comment: I got that c = 0 and 1 = a + b

Comment: @Pedro That's fine! Add your derivation and results into your question

Comment: Why derivation?

Comment: @Pedro I mean calculation :)

Comment: I can't upload the photo because the size exceeds 2mb

Comment: @Pedro it suffices you write down the method you used and the main results.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Start from the general standard equations for

- parabolas: $y=ax^2+bx+c$
- circle: $(x-x_c)^2+(y-y_c)^2=R^2$

and apply the given conditions.

---

For the parabolas since we got $c=0$ and $a+b=1$, the general equation is

$$y=ax^2+(1-a)x, \, a \in \mathbb R$$